# Write File with text from resources visual basic

Tags: vb.net, file

I'm writing some program in VB, and I want to create txt file with text from file in resources. You didn't understood, did you? So, it goes like this.

```
 Dim path As String = "c:\temp\MyTest.txt" 

    ' Create or overwrite the file. 
    Dim fs As FileStream = File.Create(path)

    ' Add text to the file. 
    Dim info As Byte() = New UTF8Encoding(True).GetBytes("This is some text in the file.")
    fs.Write(info, 0, info.Length)
    fs.Close()
```

is code for creating txt file with certain text. But, I need the following.

```
 Dim fd As New FolderBrowserDialog
    fd.ShowDialog()
```

is the only function that I have in program, and, when folder is selected, I need to create file in that folder, file's name should be config.cfg, but, text in file which is going to be created in selected folder should be text from mine txt file which is in Recources.

I've tried

```
 Dim path As String = fd.SelectedPath 
    Dim fs As FileStream = File.Create(path)

    ' upisuje tekst u fajl 
    Dim info As Byte() = New UTF8Encoding(True).GetBytes(application.startuppath &  "\..\..\Resources\config.cfg")
    fs.Write(info, 0, info.Length)
    fs.Close()
```

but the text I got in file is directory from where is my program debugged.
Any ideas to do this? :)

Comment: [GetBytes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ds4kkd55(v=vs.110).aspx) doesn't read the bytes from a file, but use the string passed as its data to be returned as a byte array. And I don't think it is a good idea to call File.Create passing the name of an existing folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you added a text file to your resources, then you can try something like this:

```
Using fbd As New FolderBrowserDialog
  If fbd.ShowDialog(Me) = DialogResult.OK Then
    File.WriteAllText(Path.Combine(fbd.SelectedPath, "config.cfg"), My.Resources.config)
  End If
End Using
```

The file I added was called config, and it made a config.txt file in my resource library.

Comment: That way works, but in meantime, I've figured out how
Here it is

New UTF8Encoding(True).GetBytes(My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(Application.StartupPath & "\..\..\Resources\config.cfg"))

Anyway, thanks @LarsTech :)